# How to handle optionals in switch statements

Tags: swift, switch-statement, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I've the following code:

```
for compareValues in [(optionalVal1, optionalVal2), (optionalVal3, optionalVal4)] {
    switch compareValues {
    case (nil, nil):
      break
    case (_, nil):
      return true
    case (nil, _):
      return false
    case let (lValue, rValue):
      return lValue < rValue
    }
}
```

This does not compile, the last line triggers this error:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

How would you suggest handling this **without** forced unwrapping `lValue` and `rValue`?

Comment: Why not forced unwrapping? There are only 4 cases and all `nil` cases are already covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To unwrap the optionals in the case statement, you can use

`case let (.some(lValue), .some(rValue)):`

Comment: Yep, or `case let (lValue?, rValue?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that if you've gotten down to the `case let (lValue, rValue)` statement, you know they're both non-`nil`, you can safely force unwrap them at that point:

```
for compareValues in values {
    switch compareValues {
    case (nil, nil):
        break
    case (_, nil):
        return true
    case (nil, _):
        return false
    case let (lValue, rValue):
        return lValue! < rValue!
    }
}
```